# How do you access your DevKit connector in a Functional unit test?

Tags: mule, mule-studio

I'm trying to verifiy certain properites of my Connector in a test. You can't do this:

```
 Object c =  registry.lookupConnector("myDevkitCon");
```

because the connector has a different type from normal connector, ie the internal mule code expects a Connector type but in our case a myDevkitConConnectorConnectionManager is returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DevKit generates classes that wrap your connector in order to add certain properties to it. One is connection pooling.

This means that if you want an instance of your connector, you have to:

- Instiantiate `myDevkitConConnectorConnectionManager`
- Call the relevant setters on it to configure it
- Call `initialise()`
- Call `acquireConnection()`

BTW this circles back to your other question [Getting functional unit tests to wait until devkit connector is connected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17491031/getting-functional-unit-tests-to-wait-until-devkit-connector-is-connected) Hopefully you now better understand my answer.